# Does glide caching works after restart by default too?

Tags: android, caching, android-glide, android-image

I'm new to caching and stuff. I have an app that fetches images from firebase storage by their url using Glide. Now it will cost me a lot if the user fetches a single image "every time" they use the app using the url (also a single image might be visible in couple of activities , so then fetching becomes redundant). So does glide cache is valid even after app restart and across all the activities or is it activity related( I mean for every activity does it has separate cache or is it just simply dependent on the url)?
Also is the caching enabled by default?
Sorry if the question sounds stupid, but otherwise the cost will increase significantly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's store some cache after app restart also the best way to invalidate a cache file is to change your identifier when the content changes (url, uri, file path etc) when possible.